# how to get total records using $project and $group in mongodb with ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I want to fetch total records for my product group by product title and order by product title. I am using monogomapper in ror.

I tried :

## tetsing code

```
@test_product_details_array_full=Product.collection.aggregate([

{"$match" => {:store_id => @store_id,  :product_active=> "yes"}},

{"$project"=> {"product_name"=> 1, "output"=> { "$toLower"=> "$product_name" }}},

{"$sort"=> {  "output"=>1 } },       

{"$project"=> {product_name: 1, _id:0}},

{"$group" => {_id: "$product_name", Product: { "$push"=> "$$ROOT"}}},       

]);
```

## testing code

I am getting blank array in out put. So how do I get proper result.

Comment: Your looking for the same sort of response that something like "Solr/ElasticSearch" does. These are specific services. With any "database" you really want "two queries". One for the current results ( usually paged ) and another the the overall "total results" matching the conditions. Trying to "shoehorn" everything in a single aggregation pipeline is a **Bad Idea**. I've posted a detailed response explaining that here before, if I can only find it again :). Use two queries. It's smart.

Comment: ya but two query not will fit in my condition. there so many process after this. Depending on this query

Comment: The basics here are to "count everything" is `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "docs": { "$push": "$$ROOT }, "count": { "$sum": 1 } }}` which results in an **extremely** large array that likely breaks the 16MB BSON limitation of MongoDB. Certainly in any "paging" operation. You need to think this though and realize it's not the smart way to do it. You also are very much surely making your full intent clear if you believe otherwise. I am responding based on what I have seen many times before.

Comment: Thanks for your response buddy!! After this process I make array for the group elements and  I will be calling in sets of 20 product per page after that as person scroll down I will be fetching it out. First I have done by group by and sorting by created date it was working but after  requirement changes need to be done by product title rest working will be same. As you know mongodb sorting features work fine on numeric values but fails on charter value or text values that reason I have to implement such working.